# Page difference is books on my mac

Tags: macos, books, ibook

Let's say book A on hardcover is 800 pages. After downloading it online, the page count is a lot more. Is this normal?

Comment: I use *books* all the time on iPhone: when changing the size of caracter in it, the page count change as well (smaller caracters means fewer pages and bigger caracters means more pages). Maybe it's the same on mac ?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this is my experience that the type setting of an electronic text contains fewer words and images than a physical book.

Have you spot checked a few chapters in the middle and then the last page to be sure your book has what you expect?

Comment: I torrented the book offline and its a little more than double.. iv flipped through the pages and it seems as it should.

Comment: Cool @JefreyRamirez based on who sets the type YMMV quite a bit.

Comment: Don't know what YMMV means..lol